# Calculating how far a robot will move in Java

Tags: java, function, math

I'm working on a project for school that requires me to move a robot. How far the robot will move each second (variable t) is calculated by the function below.

[image: Math Function]

The first function is easy. The 2nd and 3rd on the other are where I'm stuck. How would I write F(t-1)? Below is what I have so far.

```
if (t == 0) {
    distance = 2;
} else if (t > 0 && <=6 || t > 12) {
    // No clue on how to write the 2nd distance equation.
} else if (t >= 7 && <=12) {
    // No clue on how to write the 3rd distance equation.
}
```

Comment: How are you using this function? Maybe if you explain context or give the function definition you are trying might be a bit better.

Comment: you will have to use recursion to solve this problem!! do you know how to use recursion ?

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh no, you don't.

Comment: @AndyTurner any other way to do it ?

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh a loop. Recursion is a terrible approach.

Comment: *"How would I write F(t-1)?"* By writing `F(t - 1)`, assuming your method is name `F`.

Comment: A method named `F`, @Andreas? Shurely not! :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, I deserved that one, didn't I?

Comment: @SeanWang The objective of the program is to move a "robot" 100 spaces. I call a move() method to move said robot X spaces each second. The above code is from the move() method and is what determines how far the robot is to move each second.

Answer (score 5):

[Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39007625/3788176) really isn't necessary to solve this.

Note that in each of the non-zero time cases, `F(t) = F(t-1) + something`.

So you can simply do:

```
double f = 2;  /* Initial value at t=0 */
for (int t = 1; t <= maxT; ++t) {  // maxT is the maximum value of t.
  if (t <= 6 || t > 12) {
    f += /* something for case 2 */;
  } else {
    f += /* something for case 3 */;
  }
}
System.out.println(f);
```

You *can* do this with recursion, but you will get a `StackOverflowError` if `maxT` becomes modestly large; by contrast, using a loop will work for arbitrarily large `maxT` (modulo floating point errors).

---

As pointed out by @Andreas, you can do this without looping over all values of `t`:

```
double f = 2 * (maxT + 1);
for (int t = 7; t <= maxT && t <= 12; ++t) {
  f += log(t) - 2;
}
```

and you can eliminate that loop too by precomputing the values.

Comment: @Andreas do you mean by recursion, or some other way?

Comment: For t = 1..6: `F(t) = t * 2`. For t > 12: `F(t) = F(12) + (t - 12) * 2`. For t = 7..12 you can do loop, or array of 6 pre-calculated constants to calculate `12 + log(7) + log(8) + log(9) + log(10) + log(11) + log(12)` or whichever subset depending on `t`.

Comment: BTW: Variable named `F`? In uppercase? Really? ;-)

Comment: @Andreas simply to match notation in question. You might also pick up on the missing semicolon, or lack of RHS expression :)

Comment: @Andreas you can do it simpler than your three cases: simply do `F'(t) = t * 2`, and then use `log(t) - 2` for the 7..12 values.

Comment: Oops. I missed the initial value of `2`. Please add 2 to my previous formulas: For t = 0..6: `F(t) = (t + 1) << 1`, etc.

Comment: @Andreas oh right. This has a closed formula for `t > 12`. The precomputed table for the middle 6 values definitely makes the most sense in a real world use case.

Comment: Where `log(t) = Math.log(t) / Math.log(2)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem which involves the use of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).  By and large, pay close attention to the notation **F<sub>t-1</sub>**, since that refers to an evaluation of the specific function at `t-1`.

I won't write out all of the code, but I'll give you some of the basics:

- When t = 0, **return 2**.  This is your base case.
- When t is between 0 and 6 *inclusive* or greater than 12, return an evaluation of the function at t-1 and add 2.
- When t is between 7 and 12 *both inclusive*, return an evaluation of the function at t-1 and add log<sub>2</sub>(t).

Here's something to get you at least started in the right direction.

```
public double evaluateDistance(int t) {
    if(t == 0) {
        return 2;
    } else if(t > 0 && t <= 6) || (t > 12) {
        // Think about this - it would involve another call to evaluateDistance, but what is t again?
    } else if(t >= 7 && t <= 12) {
        // Another evaluation involving the function.
        // For free, the change of base operation you'll need to get base-2 evaluation for the log:
        return ??? + Math.log(t)/Math.log(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that the assignment is badly written. If the function is defined as **F(t)**, not **F<sub>t</sub>**, then **F<sub>t-1</sub>** is wrong, since it should be **F(t-1)**. Anyway, since only one recursion is present, and always for `t-1`, a loop would be better than recursion, though explaining a recursion solution first is good. *(Appears that <sub> doesn't work in comments, but you know what I mean)*

Comment: I don't disagree with that notion @Andreas.  A loop would likely be more efficient and far more straightforward, but seeing it both ways wouldn't hurt.

Comment: That was my point. *Both ways*. You're only showing the recursion way, which is the most straightforward way given the assignment, and I already applauded that, but you don't show the "better" way of looping, which will not cause `StackOverflowException` for large values of `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. Sorry if I wasn't clear on what I needed, just needed to figure out how to write the equations in the function. Think I figured it out though.

```
    public double move()
{
    int t = 0;
    if(t == 0) // After the first second, robot moves 2
    {
        distance = 2;
    }
    else if(t > 0 && t <= 6 || t > 12) // From seconds 0 to 6 and after 12, robot moves distance equation
    {
        distance = (2*t)+2;
    }
    else if(t >= 7 && t <= 12) // From seconds 7 to 12, robot moves distances equation
    {
        distance = (2*t)+(Math.log(t)/Math.log(2));
    }
    position = position + distance;
    return position;
}
```

}